# Jira - How do I force/mandate a comment on state change?

Tags: workflow, jira, state

My project is trying to implement some more stringent processes within our use of JIRA.

One thing we would like to do is force/mandate that people add a comment on transition between certain states in the workflow.

For example, on setting a story to 'Complete' (final step in our process) we want to mandate that a comment is entered to act as a summary of the final tasks on the story.

This is because we have been finding a lot of stories and tasks have been going from a development stage to complete with very little commentary being applied.

Any help, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a new screen for your transition. That way, users will see the screen prior to change the transition. Check the steps in [this document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-add-a-comment-during-a-transition-779160682.html).